# Why Sequential is faster than parallel?

Tags: multithreading, rust

The code is to count the frequency of each word in an article. In the code, I implemented sequential, muti-thread, and muti-thread with a thread pool.

I test the running time of three methods, however, I found that the sequential method is the fastest one. I use the article (data) at [37423.txt](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/37423/37423.txt), the code is at [play.rust-lang.org](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d87a28c8b3c6f9becee66956d913659f).

Below is just the single- and multi version (without the threadpool version):

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;
use std::time::SystemTime;

pub fn word_count(article: &str) -> HashMap<String, i64> {
    let now1 = SystemTime::now();
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    for word in article.split_whitespace() {
        let count = map.entry(word.to_string()).or_insert(0);
        *count += 1;
    }
    let after1 = SystemTime::now();
    let d1 = after1.duration_since(now1);
    println!("single: {:?}", d1.as_ref().unwrap());
    map
}

fn word_count_thread(word_vec: Vec<String>, counts: &Arc<Mutex<HashMap<String, i64>>>) {
    let mut p_count = HashMap::new();
    for word in word_vec {
        *p_count.entry(word).or_insert(0) += 1;
    }
    let mut counts = counts.lock().unwrap();
    for (word, count) in p_count {
        *counts.entry(word.to_string()).or_insert(0) += count;
    }
}

pub fn mt_word_count(article: &str) -> HashMap<String, i64> {
    let word_vec = article
        .split_whitespace()
        .map(|x| x.to_owned())
        .collect::<Vec<String>>();

    let count = Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new()));
    let len = word_vec.len();
    let q1 = len / 4;
    let q2 = len / 2;
    let q3 = q1 * 3;
    let part1 = word_vec[..q1].to_vec();
    let part2 = word_vec[q1..q2].to_vec();
    let part3 = word_vec[q2..q3].to_vec();
    let part4 = word_vec[q3..].to_vec();

    let now2 = SystemTime::now();

    let count1 = count.clone();
    let count2 = count.clone();
    let count3 = count.clone();
    let count4 = count.clone();

    let handle1 = thread::spawn(move || {
        word_count_thread(part1, &count1);
    });
    let handle2 = thread::spawn(move || {
        word_count_thread(part2, &count2);
    });
    let handle3 = thread::spawn(move || {
        word_count_thread(part3, &count3);
    });
    let handle4 = thread::spawn(move || {
        word_count_thread(part4, &count4);
    });
    handle1.join().unwrap();
    handle2.join().unwrap();
    handle3.join().unwrap();
    handle4.join().unwrap();
    let x = count.lock().unwrap().clone();

    let after2 = SystemTime::now();
    let d2 = after2.duration_since(now2);
    println!("muti: {:?}", d2.as_ref().unwrap());
    x
}
```

The result of mine is: single:7.93ms, muti: 15.78ms, threadpool: 25.33ms
I did the separation of the article before calculating time.
I want to know if the code has some problem.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75425107/edit) your question to include the code directly in the question (links to external sites are not enough).

Comment: That being said, your multithreaded code is actually sequential since each thread acquires the lock and keeps it while it's running, which prevents the other threads from acquiring it. As a consequence, your threads run one after the other instead of running in parallel.

Comment: I didn't read through the entire rust playground, but I would like to point out that `mspc::Receiver` does not need be be in a `Mutex` or `Arc`. They already handle reference counting and concurrency internally so all you need to do it call `clone` on the receiver to get another copy linked to the same channel.

Comment: @Locke That is actually false. "SC" in MPSC stands for "single consumer", so you can have only one receiver, which is why `Receiver` doesn't implement `Clone` (or `Sync`). The workaround to share receiver among multiple threads is indeed to wrap it in a mutex.

Comment: @jyz You're probably holding the lock on `receiver` for too long, and without a need. Try changing `while let Ok(job) = receiver.lock().unwrap().recv() { job(); }` to `loop { let Ok(job) = receiver.lock().unwrap().recv() else { break }; job(); }`

Comment: @user4815162342 my bad, I had thought the standard library one was spmc at first and copied the name without checking it. If anyone needs multiple-consumer channels, ['crossbeam-channel'](https://crates.io/crates/crossbeam-channel) is a good option (it provides mpmc channels).

Comment: @Jmb Thanks for modifying the question! I am still learning the right way to ask a question.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks for your code, it improves the performance but maybe the main problem is cloning each part in each thread. I'm still not sure.

Comment: Funnily enough the [`std::mpsc` is implemented as a wrapper around the `crossbeam-channel` `mpmc` implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/a11eb4f267ddfe4f00cb40bf94aef508c11e0862/library/std/src/sync/mpsc/mod.rs#L146-L149). @Locke @user48151623

Answer (score 3):

First you may want to know the single-threaded version is mostly parsing whitespace (and I/O, but the file is small so it will be in the OS cache on the second run). At most ~20% of the runtime is the counting that you parallelized. Here is the [cargo flamegraph](https://github.com/flamegraph-rs/flamegraph) of the single-threaded code:

[image: cargo flamegraph output, showing run_utf8_validation and is_whitespace and map_entry to equal parts]

In the multi-threaded version, it's a mess of thread creation, copying and hashmap overhead. To make sure it's not a "too little data" problem, I've used used 100x your input txt file and I'm measuring a 2x slowdown over the single-threaded version. According to the `time` command, it uses 2x CPU-time compared to wall-clock, so it seems to do *some* parallel work. The profile looks like this: ([clickable svg version](https://log2.ch/misc/wordcount_mt.svg))

[image: cargo flamegraph output, showing a big mess of memory management related stuff]

I'm not sure what to make of it exactly, but it's clear that memory management overhead has increased a lot. You seem to be copying strings for each hashmap, while an ideal wordcount would probably do zero string copying while counting.

More generally I think it's a bad idea to join the results in the threads - the way you do it (as opposed to a map-reduce pattern) the thread needs a global lock, so you could just pass the results back to the main thread instead for combining. I'm not sure if this is the main problem here, though.

---

### Optimization

To avoid string copying, use `HashMap<&str, i64>` instead of `HashMap<String, i64>`. This requires some changes (lifetime annotations and `thread::scope()`). It makes `mt_word_count()` about 6x faster compared to the old version.

With a large input I'm measuring now a 4x speedup compared to `word_count()`. (Which is the best you can hope for with four threads.) The multi-threaded version is now also faster overall, but only by ~20% or so, for the reasons explained above. (Note that the single-threaded baseline has also profited the same `&str` optimization. Also, many things could still be improved/optimized, but I'll stop here.)

```
fn word_count_thread<'t>(word_vec: Vec<&'t str>, counts: &Arc<Mutex<HashMap<&'t str, i64>>>) {
    let mut p_count = HashMap::new();
    for word in word_vec {
        *p_count.entry(word).or_insert(0) += 1;
    }
    let mut counts = counts.lock().unwrap();
    for (word, count) in p_count {
        *counts.entry(word).or_insert(0) += count;
    }
}

pub fn mt_word_count<'t>(article: &'t str) -> HashMap<&'t str, i64> {
    let word_vec = article.split_whitespace().collect::<Vec<&str>>();

    // (skipping 16 unmodified lines)

    let x = thread::scope(|scope| {
        let handle1 = scope.spawn(move || {
            word_count_thread(part1, &count1);
        });
        let handle2 = scope.spawn(move || {
            word_count_thread(part2, &count2);
        });
        let handle3 = scope.spawn(move || {
            word_count_thread(part3, &count3);
        });
        let handle4 = scope.spawn(move || {
            word_count_thread(part4, &count4);
        });
        handle1.join().unwrap();
        handle2.join().unwrap();
        handle3.join().unwrap();
        handle4.join().unwrap();
        count.lock().unwrap().clone()
    });
    let after2 = SystemTime::now();
    let d2 = after2.duration_since(now2);
    println!("muti: {:?}", d2.as_ref().unwrap());
    x
}
```

Comment: I imagine you may be able to see an additional speedup if you use mapreduce instead. The core idea being that you split the file up into sections for each thread and in the map step the threads process the data into their own maps. Then as threads finish their jobs, the reduce step involves merging the resulting maps into a single result. Mapreduce was originally intended for distributed computing of large datasets in datacenters, but I imagine it may be helpful here as well since you don't need to put a lock on the map.